# Can a HornetQ cluster take the decision of what server is going to be a live one and what a backup one?

Tags: configuration, hornetq

The aim is to have a cluster of two nodes (in a live-backup setting) with the same configuration, that is without having to have one with `<backup>true</backup>` in the configuration file and the other with `<backup>false</backup>`.

Can HornetQ be configured to take the decision of one being a live server and the other a backup server by itself somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible. HQ doesn't support this.